How to get Python buffer format string from C struct - PEP 3118
I want to know what would be the "thing" generating/inferring what a C struct's "buffer format string" should be, according to PEP 3118.
E.g. if I have some cython code that defines
cdef struct S:
    int field_1
    int field_2

if I tried to make a memoryview with type cdef S[:], there is an associated format string, something like
T{
  i:field_1:
  i:field_2:
}

What is the thing that inspects the struct definition to infer the format string?
